# Aapt dumb badging error

Tags: android, aapt

When I tried to upload signed application. Play store shows android **manifest.xml.343 error getting 'android:label'  value references does not exist**. I checked `AndroidManifest.xml` and Strings line by line but unfortunately I didn't figure out.

For simulate same error locally. I run "./aapt dump badging  myapp.apk" It shows same error.

[image]

**Manifest file**

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:name,android:theme">

    <activity
        android:name=".settings.ui.MainBoardActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/masterapp_core_theme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".settings.ui.MASplashScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" 
         />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   .........
</application>
```

Comment: show your manifest.xml

Comment: And don't shorten it. And point to line 343

Comment: Line 343  doesn't related with Android Manifest file. It's result of appt command like :
application: label='App' icon='res/drawable-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.app.oneapp.settings.ui.MASplashScreenActivity'  label='' icon=''
AndroidManifest.xml:342: error: ERROR getting 'android:label' attribute: attribute value reference does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Add below line inside `<application>` tag

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Answer (score 0):

After two day later I figure out how to approach the problem. First I found appt tool which is under the sdk/build-tools directory. When I run appt dump badging myapp.apk I saw label attribute value was empty. But problem was I have already defined it. To be sure I typed hardcoded value without referenced @string/name like that. But It doesn't solve.

Finally I compared changes in last month so problem was I defined string value at string.xml(tr) on the other module of project but I didn't define it on default string.xml. So aapt couldnt find references on default :)